# opacity в qml для Item и Rectangle

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick

Простой пример qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    width: 800; height: 800

    Rectangle {
        width: 200; height: 200
        color: "red"

        Drag.active: dragArea.drag.active

        MouseArea {
            id: dragArea
            anchors.fill: parent

            drag.target: parent
        }
    }
}
```

И файл main.cpp:

```
   QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

   QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
   viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/ex6/main.qml"));
   viewer.showExpanded();

   return app.exec();
```

Подскажите как сделать прозрачным Item ?
Если делаю так:

```
viewer.setOpacity(0.0);
```

то и Rectangle тоже становится прозрачным.

Если делаю в qml `opacity:0`, то прозрачным становится Rectangle, а прозрачность Item не меняется.

Мне нужно чтобы с помощью мышки можно было перетаскивать Rectangle по экрану монитора.

Answer (score 1):

`opacity` действует на дочерние элементы, поэтому, если вам нужно изменить прозрачность только родителя и не затронуть дочерние элементы, то надо воспользоваться полем `color`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    width: 800; height: 800
    color: "transparent" // Полностью прозрачный

    // ИЛИ В формате ARGB - первый байт это прозрачность от 0 до FF
    color: "#800000FF"

    Rectangle {
        width: 200; height: 200
        color: "red"
        opacity : 1.0

        // ...
    }
}
```